# Aligning the output of a 2 dimensional array using printf?

Tags: java, printf

I have three separate arrays, one String for the header line, and two 2-dimensional arrays. One only has values along the left side for Row Titles. The other is double and has randomly-generated values. So far an example output looks like this:

```
Test 1     Test 2     Test 3     Test Average   
Student1 65.0 61.0 64.0 63.333333333333336 
Student2 63.0 64.0 80.0 69.0 
Student3 60.0 100.0 89.0 83.0 
Student4 80.0 62.0 77.0 73.0 
Student5 68.0 75.0 68.0 70.33333333333333 
Averages 67.2 72.4 75.6 71.73333333333333
```

Here is the code:

```
import java.util.Random;
public class averages { //This part randomly generates scores to use for the students
public static int RNG1(int a) { 
    int min=60;//The minimum score a student can get is 60, for realism purposes
    int max=100;//Te max score is 100
    Random rand = new Random();
    int randomNum = rand.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;//Formula for a random number
        return randomNum;//Return result
    }   
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    String [] Header= { "    ", "Test 1", "Test 2", "Test 3", "Test Average" };//Header/column titles
    String [][] RowTitles= {//The Row titles
              {"Student1", "", "", "", ""},
              {"Student2", "", "", "", ""},
              {"Student3", "", "", "", ""},
              {"Student4", "", "", "", ""},
              {"Student5", "", "", "", ""},
              {"Averages", "", "", "", ""}
            };
    int a=0;        
    //The next bunch of lines are variables defined by random numbers
    //That will be inserted into the table as test scores
    //
        double oneone=RNG1(a);
        double onetwo=RNG1(a);
        double onethree=RNG1(a);
        double onefour=RNG1(a);
        double onefive=RNG1(a);
        double twoone=RNG1(a);
        double twotwo=RNG1(a);
        double twothree=RNG1(a);
        double twofour=RNG1(a);
        double twofive=RNG1(a);
        double threeone=RNG1(a);
        double threetwo=RNG1(a);
        double threethree=RNG1(a);
        double threefour=RNG1(a);
        double threefive=RNG1(a);

        //The following lines are averages of the individuals and of the tests
        //
        double stuone= (oneone+twoone+threeone)/3;
        double stutwo= (onetwo+twotwo+threetwo)/3;
        double stuthree= (onethree+twothree+threethree)/3;
        double stufour= (onefour+twofour+threefour)/3;
        double stufive= (onefive+twofive+threefive)/3;

        double testone= (oneone+onetwo+onethree+onefour+onefive)/5;
        double testtwo= (twoone+twotwo+twothree+twofour+twofive)/5;
        double testthree= (threeone+threetwo+threethree+threefour+threefive)/5;
        double testfour= (stuone+stutwo+stuthree+stufour+stufive)/5;        
        //array for test scores and averages
        double [][] TestScores=
            {   
                {0, oneone, twoone, threeone, stuone},
                {0, onetwo, twotwo, threetwo, stutwo},
                {0, onethree, twothree, threethree, stuthree},
                {0, onefour, twofour, threefour, stufour},
                {0, onefive, twofive, threefive, stufive},
                {0, testone, testtwo, testthree, testfour}
            };         
        //Prints out header:
        for (int  r = 0;  r < Header.length;  r++)
        {
            if(r < Header.length-1)
            {
                System.out.print("  "+Header[r]+"   ");
        } else {
                System.out.println("  "+Header[r]+"   ");
            }                   
        }       
        //Prints out student names and test scores
        for (int  r = 0;  r <= 5;  r++)
        {   
            for (int  c = 0;  c < 4;  c++)
            {              
                if(c==0){System.out.print(RowTitles[r][c]+" ");
            }                  
            if(c>0){
                System.out.print(TestScores[r][c]+" ");
            }                  
            if(c==3){
                System.out.println(TestScores[r][4]+" ");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

For the life of me, I can't figure out how to use `printf`. I assume it would be used in the last non-bracket line, instead of `System.out.println(TestScores[r][4]+" ");` but I can't get it to work. Thanks.

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve with printf? Print a specific number of decimals or something else?

Answer (score 0):

There are many examples of this on the internet. Below is one link to something very similar.

http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/158604-printf-and-alignment/

Here is how you can achieve grades that line up in rows. Just remove the heading for loop, add this code below to your first print test scores for loop after defining your TestScores array. Then comment out the inner for loop after.

```
    //To make the starting point the same on all lines I will put 8 + 5 spaces
    //which is the number of chracters in your row titles (ie.. Student1) plus
    //Five spaces for the first row padding. Your header 0 string has 4 spaces
    System.out.printf("         %s%s     %s     %s     %s\n",Header[0],Header[1],Header[2],Header[3],Header[4]);
    for (int  r = 0;  r <= 5;  r++)
    {     
        //Now do the simlar format but include padding for numbers so the line up
        // on the right. So Title + pad + row head + pad + row head + pad....etc pad + row head = 11
        //So use 11.2 to define the grades which are floats... 11.2f
        System.out.printf("%s%11.2f%11.2f%11.2f%11.2f\n",RowTitles[r][0],TestScores[r][1],TestScores[r][2],TestScores[r][3],TestScores[r][4]);
    }
```